# How to hide UINavigationItem on MKMapView pan gesture on iOS 8 like Lyft App?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uinavigationcontroller, mkmapview

Hello and thanks for checking out this question,

I am trying to emulate the functionality of the Lyft app.

[image]

In the Lyft app, when the user pans on the map, the bottom bar disappears as well as the UINavigationBar on top. I am trying to recreate this functionality in my own app

On iOS 8, there is a property on UINavigationController that lets you hide the top bar on scroll. This is nice, but can this same functionality be implemented on a mapview pan?

Also, in my app, I have a UITabBar. Does anyone know how to hide that as well??

Answer (score 3):

Add pan gesture to mapview and set delegate.

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *pan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pan:)];
pan.delegate = self;
[self.mapView addGestureRecognizer:pan];
```

Implement gesture delegate and return YES.

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}
```

In gesture selector

```
-(void)pan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)ges
{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:1 animated:1];
    [self.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

These delegate methods of MKMapView also look pretty helpful! This is great because you most likely have already implemented the MKMapView delegate !

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionWillChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
```

then you can hide

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
[self.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:YES];
```

and unhide

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
[self.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:NO];
```